# Can not use the global variable in socket.io method?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io as shown in the code below, there is a variable, bbc, to be shared among the socket.io functions.

When the 'init' is emitted on the server side, the variable bbc is given some values. But what happens is when the 'chat' event is emitted, the variable bbc is still a empty array.

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    var bbc = [];
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('init',function(){
          bbc = ['1111','1111'];
        })

        socket.on('chatMessage', function(data) {
            console.log('chatMessage',bbc,);
        });
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm, that shouldn't be happening.  You're positive the events are happening in the order in which you expect?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Your code is a bit messed up in general, you got an extra comma in the console.log(), you're missing a lot of closing brackets and parentheses. I'm assuming that this is only on Stack Overflow though. Just thought I'd let you know.